# Problems with realloc - "invalid next size"

Tags: c, realloc

In my program, I receive text from a .txt file. Here is an example of a line of text:

**12X15 de3 ds4 dn9 g2,7 m5,9 m3,1 h2,2**

I am trying to use strtok() to break up each chunk of text; I will then put each chunk as an element in an array. So an array of strings.

Here is my code so far:

```
void parseFile(char ** argv) {
    FILE *textFile;
    char *string;
    char **lineToken;
    int i;

    textFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    lineToken = malloc(sizeof(1));
    string = malloc(sizeof(MAX_CHAR));

    while(fgets(string, MAX_CHAR, textFile) != NULL) { /* Get first line of text */
        lineToken[0] = strtok(string, " "); /* Put first element in lineToken[0] */
        for(i = 1; i; i++) {
            /* Realloc because total number of elements is unknown */
            lineToken = realloc(lineToken, i + 1);

            /* Put new strtok'd string into lineToken[i] */
            lineToken[i] = strtok(NULL, " "); 
        }

        for(i = 0; i; i++) {
            move(i, 0);
            printw("%s", lineToken[i]);
            refresh();
        }
    }
    free(lineToken);
    free(string);
} /* End of function */
```

But I keep getting this realloc error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./bin/a3RunMe: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x01f2a270 ***
Aborted
```

Comment: Sure you meant `printf` instead of `printw`.

Comment: My apologies. I'm using the ncurses library, so printing text to the screen needs printw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most likely problem:

```
lineToken = malloc(sizeof(1));
```

Here you allocate the size of an integer literal, but `lineToken` needs at least `sizeof(*lineToken)` (or `sizeof(char *)`) bytes. The size of an integer and the size of a pointer may not be the same, especially on a 64-bit platform (where `int` is four bytes and pointers are eight bytes).

So when you do

```
lineToken[0] = strtok(string, " ")
```

you write beyond what's allocated (buffer overflow) and overwrite data put there by the allocator.

There's also a problem with the `realloc` call which will allocate `i + 1` *bytes*. So even when you're on a 32-bit platform (where the size of `int` just happens to be the same as the size of a pointer) you will reallocate the pointer from being four bytes to two bytes in the first iteration of the loop.

---

You also have other problems, like these loops:

```
for(i = 1; i; i++)
```

Remember that in C all non-zero values are true, and when will `i` ever be zero in that loop?

Comment: Okay, so I fixed the iteration of the loops. I think the condition of "string != NULL" should suffice. Now, with the realloc call... what would you recommend I put there? I assume you understand what I am trying to do?

Comment: @user2359287 Remember that you are allocating multiples of `sizeof(char*)` bytes, so `sizeof(char*) * (i + 1)`.

Comment: That makes so much sense. I added what you suggested and it works! Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This `for` loop is infinite...

```
for(i = 1; i; i++)
{
        lineToken = realloc(lineToken, i + 1); /* Realloc because total number of elements is unknown */
        lineToken[i] = strtok(NULL, " "); /* Put new strtok'd string into lineToken[i] */
}
```

Condition `i` is always evaluates to `TRUE` for `i != 0`.

You might be keep incrementing and allocating in the loop, hence that error.